# When does creating a file upload field by Javascript fail?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, file-upload

In a webpage I'm making I'd like to give people the option to upload several files at once. I'd like to make it in such a way that as soon as a file upload field is filled, another one is created beneath it.

Now, there's no problem in attaching myself to `onchange` and creating a new field by Javascript, but I seem to remember one problem about this: In some browser (I think it was some version of IE) file upload fields created with Javascript didn't work. They appeared, you could select files, but they never got uploaded. The only way to make a file upload field work was to render it in the original HTML (thus workarounds with iframes were born).

Now, that was some time ago and I can't remember which version of IE it was (or if it was IE at all). Also searching in google and SO yields no results - it fact, in several places it is suggested to create such fields by JS. So - did I just dream this, or is this an actual problem? If it is, then for which browsers?

Comment: I really can't remember ever having this problem.

Comment: If so, then add this as an answer. Perhaps I am mis-remembering something. I'll accept it if no others show up for a day.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem - The one thing you can't do through JS is setting the value of the file input because of the obvious security implications, but other than that creating file inputs through JS is doable. Worst case scenario you are thinking about something really old (IE 5 or earlier) in which case I'd be inclined to say "who cares?"

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino - exactly. Even if it's IE6 - I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/). It's a small JavaScript and Flash file upload framework that might make your job a little easier. They have a number of examples, including multiple file uploads, at http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm.

Comment: I know of it, but I'd like to stay flash-free for now. Also, since the person uploading will need to specify some metadata for every image, uploading the files one-by-one kinda makes sense.